# Unfortunately, System UI has stopped. Is this an App error?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

When I try to clear apps (by using the home button), I face "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped" alertDialog.
Is this because of my app error (Not all the times, some times)? or its belongs to the Android system?

If it is belongs to Application ERROR, How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: yes .app error.

Comment: which device it is?

Comment: How to handle it.? can you brief little

Comment: Version 6.0 Moto E

Comment: i think  System UI has stopped is not app error ... i think it is an error of third party Launcher or system

Comment: I am working with an app that related to Map, When people(testers)  install my app they are getting this error (not all the time), what may be the issue and how can I solve it

Comment: Me too got the same problem , but mine was on the **Real Device**? , what is probably the solution?, becaause i just took my phone to the carl center to recover back my **Launcher**, how can i recover this , please , I saw several answers but they are on Emulators only , what is the solution , please?

Answer (score 0):

It is for third party launcher or system error, not an app error. There is no way you can handle it. 
But for being sure you can add code example so that we can look if there is any memory leak or too much operations on Main thread. Thanks.

Comment: Its a launcher/system error, but it can be caused by an app; specifically an app with an icon whose pixel width is larger than screen. (confirmed - I saw this when a hi-res original image was mistakenly used instead of the shrunk icon version.) Maybe can also happen if app crashes while system making preview image to show in apps list (speculative)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and nothing could help me. Fortunately, I found the solution:

1. Navigate your device "Settings";
2. Select "Applications", tap on "Menu";
3. Select "Show system application" in pull-down menu;
4. Then find "System Interface" among all applications. In "Memory"
   section perform clearing all data and cache.

https://android-fix.com/android-errors/41-unfortunately-system-ui-has-stopped.html﻿