# System UI crash when authorizing adb

Tags: android, adb

I have been experiencing a problem.
I'm trying to authorize my rooted android device (Asus Zenfone GO) for ADB.
Developer options are on and USB debug, as well. Unfortunately, if I plug the phone and start the ADB server on my pc, instead of showing the authorization popup on the phone, the following message is shown "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped." and the user interface crashes.
Any ideas about how to solve the problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387398/unfortunately-system-ui-has-stopped-is-this-an-app-error

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work for me :(